# JavaScript always check the input

Tags: javascript

I'm going to start off with an apology, I am totally new to this, so excuse my ignorance.

I can't manage to find a simple example of how to check html input with JavaScript.

I'm building a search function and I don't know how to get my code to check what a user input and to always be checking what they say. Not fire a set number of times.

ie.

User types "a" into an `<input>`.

User input is set to a variable and will constantly update.

In this case `var userInput = 'a'`.

I suppose another way to phrase it is I want `document.getElementById('userInput')` but to get it constantly.

I hope I was clear!

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question before we can give any answers. Are you just looking to retrieve an HTML field value with JavaScript, or are you asking how to send that value to a Node.js server?

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't sure what was important to add. The former as apposed to the latter. When a user types into the input I'm looking for that to initiate a function. Right now I can only get it to pull through once when the document is ready.

Comment: Ah, well then that's just browser-based JavaScript, not Node.js. Node.js is server-side JavaScript. I've edited your question to remove the Node.js tag/references and answered your question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an HTML text input like this:

```
<input id="userInput" type="text">
```

To listen for when a key is pressed in that textfield:

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput');
userInput.onkeyup = function() {
  console.log(this.value);
};
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
$("#userInput").keyup(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: .onkeyup! This is a huge relief. I don't want to admit how many days I tried to find this. Thanks mate.